# Fix error in spectrum color picker

Tags: javascript, jslint

I implemented [spectrum color picker](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/), and I'm trying to fix up the JSLint errors. I have 2 types of errors which I can't seem to fix. Here are the errors

> - *'var'* was used before it was defined
> - Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function

Here's the code with the errors:

```
(function (factory) {
    "use strict";

    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) { // AMD
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === "object" && typeof module === "object") { // CommonJS
        module.exports = factory;
    } else { // Browser
        factory(jQuery);
    }
})(function($, undefined) {
    "use strict";
   ...
```

`define`, `exports`, and `module` all have the error that it's not defined.

Then the second function: `})(function($, undefined) {` has the 2<sup>nd</sup> error mentioned above. So I checked up [that error](https://jslinterrors.com/move-the-invocation-into-the-parens-that-contain-the-function), and I tried what it said: `}(function ($, undefined) ) {` I moved the closing parenthesis to the end, and I now get the following error:

> Expected '{' and instead saw '}'.

How can I fix the 2 errors mentioned above?

Comment: Where are define, exports, and module defined?  Are they global vars or passed in somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting `})(function($, undefined) {` into `}(function ($, undefined) ) {` is erroneous because you need to move the {} inside the parentheses as well, like so:

```
(function() {
    ...
}(function() { ... }));
```

With regards to the undefined errors you're getting, just put this comment at the top of your JS file:

```
/*global define, module, exports*/
```

Feel free to add some other common variables if you need to exclude them as well:

```
/*global define, module, exports, document, window, alert, console, require*/
```

Comment: Alternatively add them to a `.jslintrc` file so that the globals affect all the files rather than just that one.